# Mongodb $unwind equivalent using lodash

Tags: javascript, mongodb, lodash

I have the following object:

```
data =[
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T06:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T06:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T06:10:57.617Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800,
          "O3": 300
        }
      },
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T06:12:00.000Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800,
          "O3": 300.25,
          "NO2": 100.45
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T10:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T07:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T07:10:57.617Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:46:55.256Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 689.325,
          "CO": 47.849
        }
      },
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:52:22.233Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 200,
          "PM10": 200
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ101",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:55:32.124Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to realize what is possible in MongoDB using $unwind but in javascript using *lodash*.
So far I was able to flatten data with flatMap as:

```
const output = _(data).flatMap('samples').value()
console.log(output)
```

But I lost the station name that is fundamental!
The output of my code is:

```
[
  {
    t: '2020-09-03T06:10:57.617Z',
    data: { PM1: 100, PM10: 800, O3: 300 }
  },
  {
    t: '2020-09-03T06:12:00.000Z',
    data: { PM1: 100, PM10: 800, O3: 300.25, NO2: 100.45 }
  },
  { t: '2020-09-03T07:10:57.617Z', data: { PM1: 100, PM10: 800 } },
  { t: '2020-09-03T09:46:55.256Z', data: { PM1: 689.325, CO: 47.849 } },
  { t: '2020-09-03T09:52:22.233Z', data: { PM1: 200, PM10: 200 } },
  { t: '2020-09-03T09:55:32.124Z', data: { PM1: 100, PM10: 800 } }
]
```

I would like to add to each object in the resulting array a member named station_name that resemble the original member in data.station.name.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
data =[
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T06:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T06:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T06:10:57.617Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800,
          "O3": 300
        }
      },
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T06:12:00.000Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800,
          "O3": 300.25,
          "NO2": 100.45
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T10:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T07:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T07:10:57.617Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ103",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:46:55.256Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 689.325,
          "CO": 47.849
        }
      },
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:52:22.233Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 200,
          "PM10": 200
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
  {
    "id": "AQ103_2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "station": {
      "name": "AQ101",
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          45,
          12.45
        ]
      }
    },
    "samples": [
      {
        "t": "2020-09-03T09:55:32.124Z",
        "data": {
          "PM1": 100,
          "PM10": 800
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

let unwindedData = data.map(doc => doc.samples.map(sample => ({
  ...doc,
  samples: sample
}))).flat();

console.log(unwindedData);
```

This simulates the $unwind method pretty well but doesn't require lodash.

Map each doc to an array of single sample objects, then flatten.

```
data.map(doc => doc.samples.map(sample => ({
  ...doc,
  samples: sample
}))).flat()
```

Note: the snippet running on SO shows a ref comment as station in log output but the actual output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GitGitBoom,
by further elaborating your suggestion I came to the following code:

```
let r=data.map(doc => doc.samples.map(sample => ({
  station:doc.station.name,
  t:sample.t,
   ...sample.data
}))).flat()
console.table(r)
```

That provide exactly what I was looking for:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ (index) │ station │             t              │   PM1   │ PM10 │   O3   │  NO2   │   CO   │
├─────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│    0    │ 'AQ103' │ '2020-09-03T06:10:57.617Z' │   100   │ 800  │  300   │        │        │
│    1    │ 'AQ103' │ '2020-09-03T06:12:00.000Z' │   100   │ 800  │ 300.25 │ 100.45 │        │
│    2    │ 'AQ103' │ '2020-09-03T07:10:57.617Z' │   100   │ 800  │        │        │        │
│    3    │ 'AQ103' │ '2020-09-03T09:46:55.256Z' │ 689.325 │      │        │        │ 47.849 │
│    4    │ 'AQ103' │ '2020-09-03T09:52:22.233Z' │   200   │ 200  │        │        │        │
│    5    │ 'AQ101' │ '2020-09-03T09:55:32.124Z' │   100   │ 800  │        │        │        │
└─────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```